# JBOSS Wildfly: ARJUNA016082: Synchronizations are not allowed! when sending message to JMS Queue triggered by @PostPersist

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss, jms, wildfly

I have a question about the error message in the title. I am trying to achieve the following:

- Inserting an entity via `EntityManager.merge(...);`
- `@PostPersist` listener of the entity should send a message to a JMS Queue (HornetQ) to notify other parts of the system about the insertion of the entity.

The method annotated with `@PostPersist` is invoked perfectly, but when sending the message, I get the error message below. Looks like sending the message triggers the error, but why?

Another strange behavior is, that if I trigger the same action a second time, the error does not appear and the message is send to the queue.

I am using the following environment:

- JBOSS Wildfly CR1
- Hibernate 4.3.0
- JDK 1.7.0.25

Any help is appreciated. If you need any further information, I will try to provide it.

**Edit:**

- I found out that sending the message after the call to `EntityManager.merge(...);` works without any error. Only when triggering the message via `@PostPersist` the error occurs.
- The error exactly occurs, when creating an object message with the following code (context is a JMSContext object (JMS 2.0)):

  ```
  context.createProducer().send(destination, context.createObjectMessage(aMessage));
  ```

**2nEdit:**

- Calling `EntityManager.flush()` after `EntitiyManager.merge(...)` is a workaround which does not produce the error. I can work with that, but I would like to understand the reason.

**The Full Error Message:**

> 09:58:07,193 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (default task-5) JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component CustomerApplication for method public com.hji.tis.domain.model.customer.Customer com.hji.tis.application.CustomerApplication.saveCustomer(com.hji.tis.domain.model.customer.Customer): javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction rolled back
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleEndTransactionException(CMTTxInterceptor.java:139) [wildfly-ejb3-8.0.0.CR1.jar:8.0.0.CR1]
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.endTransaction(CMTTxInterceptor.java:119) [wildfly-ejb3-8.0.0.CR1.jar:8.0.0.CR1]
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:277) [wildfly-ejb3-8.0.0.CR1.jar:8.0.0.CR1]
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:340) [wildfly-ejb3-8.0.0.CR1.jar:8.0.0.CR1]
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:239) [wildfly-ejb3-8.0.0.CR1.jar:8.0.0.CR1]
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [wildfly-ejb3-8.0.0.CR1.jar:8.0.0.CR1]
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:43) [wildfly-ejb3-8.0.0.CR1.jar:8.0.0.CR1]
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.AuthorizationInterceptor.processInvocation(AuthorizationInterceptor.java:123) [wildfly-ejb3-8.0.0.CR1.jar:8.0.0.CR1]
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:95) [wildfly-ejb3-8.0.0.CR1.jar:8.0.0.CR1]
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64) [wildfly-ejb3-8.0.0.CR1.jar:8.0.0.CR1]
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [wildfly-ejb3-8.0.0.CR1.jar:8.0.0.CR1]
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:55) [wildfly-ejb3-8.0.0.CR1.jar:8.0.0.CR1]
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:325)
>       at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:437)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:61)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:325)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
>       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:185)
>       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:182)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
>       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:73)
>       at com.hji.tis.application.CustomerApplication$$$view10.saveCustomer(Unknown Source) [tis-model.jar:]
>       at com.hji.tis.ui.request.CreateRequestUiBean.saveCustomer(CreateRequestUiBean.java:384)
>       at com.hji.tis.ui.request.CreateRequestUiBean.sendRequests(CreateRequestUiBean.java:447)
>       at com.hji.tis.ui.request.CreateRequestUiBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.sendRequests(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
>       at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:326) [javax.el-3.0-b07.jar:3.0-b07]
>       at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:536) [javax.el-3.0-b07.jar:3.0-b07]
>       at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256) [javax.el-3.0-b07.jar:3.0-b07]
>       at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:269) [javax.el-3.0-b07.jar:3.0-b07]
>       at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304) [javax.el-3.0-b07.jar:3.0-b07]
>       at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40) [weld-core-impl-2.1.1.Final.jar:2013-12-03 09:59]
>       at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50) [weld-core-impl-2.1.1.Final.jar:2013-12-03 09:59]
>       at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40) [weld-core-impl-2.1.1.Final.jar:2013-12-03 09:59]
>       at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50) [weld-core-impl-2.1.1.Final.jar:2013-12-03 09:59]
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
>       at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
>       at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
>       at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
>       at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:87)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
>       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:70)
>       at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:113)
>       at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationCallHandler.java:52)
>       at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:51)
>       at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:61)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:56)
>       at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:67)
>       at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:70)
>       at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)
>       at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
>       at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)
>       at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:240)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:73)
>       at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:146)
>       at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:164)
>       at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:654)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
>
> Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: ARJUNA016053: Could not commit transaction.
>       at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1178)
>       at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.commit(BaseTransaction.java:126)
>       at com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.commit(BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.java:75)
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.endTransaction(CMTTxInterceptor.java:93) [wildfly-ejb3-8.0.0.CR1.jar:8.0.0.CR1]
>       ... 89 more
>
> Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: error during managed flush
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl$CallbackExceptionMapperImpl.mapManagedFlushFailure(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1887) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.0.Final.jar:4.3.0.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.java:115) [hibernate-core-4.3.0.Final.jar:4.3.0.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.RegisteredSynchronization.beforeCompletion(RegisteredSynchronization.java:50) [hibernate-core-4.3.0.Final.jar:4.3.0.Final]
>       at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.SynchronizationImple.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationImple.java:76)
>       at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:358)
>       at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.end(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:91)
>       at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.AtomicAction.commit(AtomicAction.java:162)
>       at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1166)
>       ... 92 more
>
> Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ARJUNA016082: Synchronizations are not allowed! Transaction status isActionStatus.RUNNING
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:163) [wildfly-ejb3-8.0.0.CR1.jar:8.0.0.CR1]
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:253) [wildfly-ejb3-8.0.0.CR1.jar:8.0.0.CR1]
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:342) [wildfly-ejb3-8.0.0.CR1.jar:8.0.0.CR1]
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:239) [wildfly-ejb3-8.0.0.CR1.jar:8.0.0.CR1]
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [wildfly-ejb3-8.0.0.CR1.jar:8.0.0.CR1]
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:43) [wildfly-ejb3-8.0.0.CR1.jar:8.0.0.CR1]
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:95) [wildfly-ejb3-8.0.0.CR1.jar:8.0.0.CR1]
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64) [wildfly-ejb3-8.0.0.CR1.jar:8.0.0.CR1]
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [wildfly-ejb3-8.0.0.CR1.jar:8.0.0.CR1]
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:55) [wildfly-ejb3-8.0.0.CR1.jar:8.0.0.CR1]
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:325)
>       at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:428)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:61)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:325)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
>       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:185)
>       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:182)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
>       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:73)
>       at com.hji.tis.infrastructure.eventbus.DomainEventBus$$$view7.fire(Unknown Source) [tis-model.jar:]
>       at com.hji.tis.domain.BaseEntity.fireEvent(BaseEntity.java:183) [tis-model.jar:]
>       at com.hji.tis.domain.model.customer.Customer.postPersist(Customer.java:172) [tis-model.jar:]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.jpa.EntityCallback.performCallback(EntityCallback.java:47) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.0.Final.jar:4.3.0.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.jpa.CallbackRegistryImpl.callback(CallbackRegistryImpl.java:112) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.0.Final.jar:4.3.0.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.jpa.CallbackRegistryImpl.postCreate(CallbackRegistryImpl.java:71) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.0.Final.jar:4.3.0.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPostInsertEventListener.onPostInsert(JpaPostInsertEventListener.java:55) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.0.Final.jar:4.3.0.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.postInsert(EntityInsertAction.java:176) [hibernate-core-4.3.0.Final.jar:4.3.0.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:144) [hibernate-core-4.3.0.Final.jar:4.3.0.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:453) [hibernate-core-4.3.0.Final.jar:4.3.0.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:345) [hibernate-core-4.3.0.Final.jar:4.3.0.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350) [hibernate-core-4.3.0.Final.jar:4.3.0.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56) [hibernate-core-4.3.0.Final.jar:4.3.0.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1218) [hibernate-core-4.3.0.Final.jar:4.3.0.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:421) [hibernate-core-4.3.0.Final.jar:4.3.0.Final]
>       at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.java:110) [hibernate-core-4.3.0.Final.jar:4.3.0.Final]
>       ... 98 more
>
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ARJUNA016082: Synchronizations are not allowed! Transaction status isActionStatus.RUNNING
>       at org.jboss.as.messaging.deployment.JMSContextProducer$JMSContextWrapper.getDelegate(JMSContextProducer.java:243) [wildfly-messaging-8.0.0.CR1.jar:8.0.0.CR1]
>       at org.jboss.as.messaging.deployment.JMSContextProducer$JMSContextWrapper.createProducer(JMSContextProducer.java:257) [wildfly-messaging-8.0.0.CR1.jar:8.0.0.CR1]
>       at com.hji.tis.infrastructure.eventbus.DomainEventBus.fire(DomainEventBus.java:80) [tis-model.jar:]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
>       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53)
>       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:406)
>       at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:82) [wildfly-weld-8.0.0.CR1.jar:8.0.0.CR1]
>       at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:93) [wildfly-weld-8.0.0.CR1.jar:8.0.0.CR1]
>       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53)
>       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43) [wildfly-ejb3-8.0.0.CR1.jar:8.0.0.CR1]
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:406)
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.concurrency.ContainerManagedConcurrencyInterceptor.processInvocation(ContainerManagedConcurrencyInterceptor.java:104) [wildfly-ejb3-8.0.0.CR1.jar:8.0.0.CR1]
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:406)
>       at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:55) [weld-core-impl-2.1.1.Final.jar:2013-12-03 09:59]
>       at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:84) [wildfly-weld-8.0.0.CR1.jar:8.0.0.CR1]
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>       at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45) [wildfly-ee-8.0.0.CR1.jar:8.0.0.CR1]
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
>       at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53)
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.singleton.SingletonComponentInstanceAssociationInterceptor.processInvocation(SingletonComponentInstanceAssociationInterceptor.java:52) [wildfly-ejb3-8.0.0.CR1.jar:8.0.0.CR1]
>       at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)
>       at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:251) [wildfly-ejb3-8.0.0.CR1.jar:8.0.0.CR1]
>       ... 150 more
>
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ARJUNA016082: Synchronizations are not allowed! Transaction status isActionStatus.RUNNING
>       at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.registerSynchronizationImple(TransactionImple.java:375)
>       at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.registerSynchronization(TransactionImple.java:352)
>       at org.jboss.as.messaging.deployment.JMSContextProducer$JMSContextWrapper.getDelegate(JMSContextProducer.java:228) [wildfly-messaging-8.0.0.CR1.jar:8.0.0.CR1]
>       ... 188 more

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug to me.

org.jboss.as.messaging.deployment.JMSContextProducer$JMSContextWrapper.getDelegate() shouldn't register a Synchronization with the Transaction.  Instead, the TransactionSynchronizationRegistry should be used.

Please create a https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY bug report for this.

Comment: Was an issue ever created for this? I still encounter this issue (WF14, so its been around for a while).

Comment: Issue: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-11450 Forum thread; https://developer.jboss.org/message/985649?et=watches.email.thread#985649